# How to resolve method 'getT1' in 'Void'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following method:

```
public void countLetters() {
    Flux.just("alpha", "bravo", "charlie")
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .flatMap(s -> Flux.fromArray(s.split("")))
            .groupBy(String::toString)
            .sort(Comparator.comparing(GroupedFlux::key))
            .flatMap(group -> Mono.just(group.key()).and(group.count()))
            .map(keyAndCount ->
                    keyAndCount.getT1() + " => " + keyAndCount.getT2())
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

It gives me these errors:

> Cannot resolve method 'getT1' in 'Void'
>
> Cannot resolve method 'getT2' in 'Void'

I'm not sure what this means. Is it because my method is void or is it some other reason?

Comment: Whatever you think `Mono.and()` does, isn't what it does.

Comment: I saw the Flux in a book. Trying to understand it so typed it out and attempted to run it. What's the issue with `Mono.and`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
            .flatMap(group -> Mono.just(group.key()).and(group.count()))
```

You need

```
            .map(group -> new Tuple2<>(group.key(), group.count()))
```

The issues in your flatMap:

- It doesn't need to be a flat map at all. You are mapping your response in a "1 to 1" fashion without any further reactive streams, so the `Mono.just` isn't needed.
- `Mono.and` joins 2 `Monos` and will produce a new `Mono<Void>` which is a mono that only completes (when all joined monos complete), meaning it has no result (doesn't emit any values). This means that `.map` and `.flatMap` on this mono will accept a `Void` as param (main reason for your compile time error). Not just that, but they will never be called, as `Mono<Void>` don't emit any `Void` values, they just complete (similar to `Completable` from RxJava).

For example, if you have

```
Mono<File> downloadFile = ...;
Mono<Long> calculateNumber = ...;
```

and you perform

```
Mono<Void> test = downloadFile.and(calculateNumber);
```

You would create a new `Mono` that completes when both monos complete, but throws away both values!

So:

```
test.map(v -> {
   // v is type of "Void", and this map will never be called!
   System.out.println("this will never be printed!");
   return 0;
}).doFinally((signalType) -> {
            System.out.println("this will be called!");
        }).subscribe(
                v -> System.out.println("wont be called, nothing is emitted!"),
                err -> System.out.println("this might be called, if the stream emits an error"),
                () -> System.out.println("this will be called, as its a completion handler!")
        );
```

The mono `test` will terminate/complete after both monos joined with `and` complete.

If you really want a `flatMap` with `Mono.just`-ing the values of the tuple, you could use `Mono.zip`.

Comment: Ah, was just about to post this - got it working when I used this line `.flatMap(group -> Mono.just(Tuples.of(group.key(), group.count().block())))`. Thanks for the info. Will have to take a little time to get my head around what you just said.

Comment: @runnerpaul i added an example, if that helps clear it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

`Tuple2` **Cannot be used directly**.

So,
Instead of

```
            .flatMap(group -> Mono.just(group.key()).and(group.count()))
```

You need

```
            .flatMap(group -> Mono.just(group.key()).zipWith(group.count()))
```

`zipWith` function will combine the result from this mono and another into a `Tuple2`.